# Uploading an Excel sheet with a specified sheet name using oledb

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to upload an excel sheet using asp.net and know the structure of the columns in the sheet so that it would be helpful in using sqlbulkcopy to upload to a table with similar structure.

any answers would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know how to do the uploading part, so I concentrate on the Excel part.

There are a bunch of 3rd-Party tools to read Excel files in .NET, which in my experience is way more flexible than using the capabilities that .NET has out-of-the-box. However here's one way you can do it:

```
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
    connection.Open();

    using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";

        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                /* read data here */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind:

1. The Jet OLE DB provider reads a registry key to determine how many rows are to be read to guess the type of the source column. The registry setting is: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows. By default, the value for this key is 8. Hence, the provider scans the first 8 rows of the source data to determine the data types for the columns (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281517) The valid range of values for the TypeGuessRows key is 0 to 16. However, if the value is 0, the number of source rows scanned is 16384.
2. On 64-bit systems the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver is currently not supported.
3. For more info on the parameters used in the connection string see here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel
4. "HDR=Yes" in the connection string indicates that the provider will not include the first row of the cell range (which may be a header row) in the RecordSet. So if the header row gives you  information that you need to build the sqlbulkcopy commands you should set it to "HDR=No".

Comment: Thanks for reply,I want to know the schema of the table in sheet so that i can create an exact table with same columns so that it would be easy in using SqlBulkcopy.

Comment: You can infer the Excel table schema from the information the DbDataReader gives you (the /* read data here */ section in my sample above). For example: dr.FieldCount gives you the number of columns, dr.GetFieldType gets you the data type, dr.GetSchemaTable returns a System.Data.DataTable that describes the column metadata etc.